# Play alternate sound on stream signal or silence

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, audio-streaming, audio-player

I definitely don't have an idea of how to go about this, but I'm sure someone out there does.

1. I've got a friend who has a music Streaming Channel
2. He wants that every time a block of songs ends, a beep sound triggers an audio ID saying hello on a personalized manner depending on the region the listener is in
3. At that time the original audio stream keeps rolling on the buffer on total silence until
4. another signal from the original stream turns off the overlaid message and goes on with the next block of music.

This is probably possible with javascript (I hope) I've seen lots of examples but none that meets my need.

Any Ideas out there?

Comment: Does it have to be a beep?  Why not a signal in the metadata?

Comment: Hello Brad, because the audio is not played directly from files, it's sent to shoutcast via direct sound, plug to plug.

Comment: SHOUTcast supports metadata.  Most places trigger ads like these based on metadata changes.

Comment: I know it does, but the signal is not controlled by software, its an analog signal, a continues, endless, long, long stream that goes forever. no metadata place in an analog signal.

Comment: Right, but what I'm suggesting is to do whatever signaling for saying hello and what not on the source end, not on the receiving end.  It will be much easier to do this on the source end than to hack a bunch of stuff in client-side.  Even if you're listening for a beep or whatever, write that code on the source end.  Much simpler this way.  Liquidsoap has a lot of functionality you can potentially use for this.  Source listens for the beep, then drops the appropriate metadata into the stream.

Comment: Thank You for suggesting Liquidsoap, I'll take a dive into the documentation. It's so interesting. Brad You Rock